# Hiding embedded YouTube video pop-up annotations

Tags: video, youtube, annotations, embed, hide

When I'm embedding a YT video, using YT.player third party API, doesn't make sense what kind of parameters are passed, the YT annotations popping-up for a couple of seconds at the beginning of the video. After a while - about 2-3 seconds these annotations go hidden. I would like to hide them from the beginning, what would be the solution then?

Here's the code which is used to embed the video.

```js
if ($('.youtube-background-video').length){
    // Loading Youtube IFrame Player API code
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag,firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    var bgVideoId = $('.youtube-background-video').data('video-id');

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        player = new YT.Player('yt-bg-player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: bgVideoId,
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1, // Auto-play the video on load
                disablekb: 1, // disble keyboard
                controls: 0, // Hide pause/play buttons in player
                showinfo: 0, // Hide the video title
                modestbranding: 1, // Hide the Youtube Logo
                loop: 1, // Run the video in a loop
                fs: 0, // Hide the full screen button
                autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
                rel: 0, // show releated videos
                enablejsapi: 1, // allow control via api
                iv_load_policy: 3 // dont show annotations
            },
            events: {
                onReady: function (e) {
                    e.target.mute();
                    e.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
                    e.target.playVideo();
                },

                onStateChange: function (e) {
                    if (e && e.data === 1) {
                        var videoHolder = document.getElementById('home-banner-box');
                        if (videoHolder && videoHolder.id) {
                            videoHolder.classList.remove('loading');
                        }
                    } else if (e && e.data === 0) {
                        e.target.playVideo()
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

[image]

I've tried to change the parameters and some CSS tricks either but in vain.